# Enable Migrations doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add asp.net identity to my Web API, I typed in the `package manager console`:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot determine a valid start-up project. Using project 'MySite.API' instead. Your configuration file and working directory may not be set as expected. Use the -StartUpProjectName parameter to set one explicitly. Use the -Verbose switch for more information.
>
> **No context type was found in the assembly 'MySite.API'.**

I made sure that the Web API project is the default project and the one that is selected on the dropdown.

this is my `packages.Config`:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Any idea what can causes that?

Comment: Does it work if you add `-ProjectName MySite.Api`

Comment: @PeterMorris I tried, didn't work.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but, I'm assuming you're not very familiar with EF code first so I strongly suggest you to follow this tutorial [EF tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Run the `Enable-Migrations` command in Package Manager Console

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <String> -StartUpProjectName <String> -Verbose
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the `<String>` argument?

Comment: Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <YourprojectName> -StartUpProjectName <DefaultProjectName> -Verbose

Comment: I ran it but got an error: `No context type was found in the assembly 'Mivhar.API'.`

Comment: Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <datacontextProcejectName>StartUpProjectName <YourMainProjectName> -Verbose

datacontextProcejectName:Your Context ProjectName

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how can I know what is my `datacontextProcejectName`?

Comment: are using different Project for dataContext?
if yes than use this datacontextprojectname
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <contextProjectname> -StartUpProjectName <YourprojectName> -Verbose 


if using single Project than

Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <YourprojectName> -StartUpProjectName <YourprojectName> -Verbose 

n make sure you are using code first approach